# Entity Framework Code First Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets and custom entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

My stored procedure returns two sets of result.
ProductSearchResult and ProductSizeResult are not entities in my case, hence i get an exception The EntitySet name 'Database.ProductSearchResult' could not be found.

I don't want to create Entity in dbcontext for each of my procedure results, is there any solution to map stored procedure to custom objects.

```
        try
        {
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.Translate<ProductSearchResult>(reader, "ProductSearchResult", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
            reader.NextResult();
            productSizeResults = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.Translate<ProductSizeResult>(reader, "ProductSizeResult", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
```

My custom entities,

```
public class ProductSearchResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

    public int Price{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductSizeResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

My Stored Procedure,

```
ALTER PROC GetProductResult @PrimaryCategory nvarchar(100)
AS

select P.Id
,P.Name
,PI.AvailableQuantity
,PI.Price
from Products P
inner join ProductInventories PI on P.Id = PI.ProductId
--where clause

select CA.Name Size,count(1) Count 
from Products P
inner join ProductInventories PI on P.Id = PI.ProductId
inner join CustomAttributes CA on PI.CustomAttributeID = CA.Id
--where clause
group by CA.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Translate<TElement> method enables you to execute a standard ADO.NET query against a data source and translate the returned data rows into **entity** objects.

(my emphasis)

That means that the types `ProductSearchResult` and `ProductSizeResult` must be mapped types (entity types). This fact was already revealed --more or less-- by the `MergeOption` parameter. That is about how to add the objects to the change tracker, which doesn't make sense for non-entity types.